# How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I want to compile my program with the latest version of `gcc`.

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with gcc 4.8.2, however there's 4.9.0 available, moreover, I see that it is available as a package: [`gcc-4.9`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.9). I tried to install it

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
```

but it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-base' for regex 'gcc-4.9'
gcc-4.9-base is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Looks like it is already installed, just not as the default one? How do I utilize it to build my program?

Comment: If you want to install `gcc-4.8` , you need to use `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8`. `gcc-4.9` ,`gcc-4.8` , `gcc-4.7`, `gcc-4.6` all are in [Ubuntu main repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

Comment: @Dumindu But how do I use `gcc-4.9` specifically?

Comment: Uninstall others and install 4.9.

Comment: @Dumindu Wait, did you just tell me to do what I just did? It is not working.

Comment: switch to root user : `sudo su -`
goto `/usr/bin` then run `ls -l gcc*` and post your output. then I'll post your answer.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

The best way to correctly install gcc-4.9 and set it as your default gcc version use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
```

The `--slave`, with `g++`, will cause `g++` to be switched along with `gcc`, to the same version. But, at this point gcc-4.9 will be your only version configured in `update-alternatives`, so add 4.8 to `update-alternatives`, so there actually is an alternative, by using:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
```

Then you can check which one that is set, and change back and forth using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

If you have an issue with update-alternatives gcc priority 60 not being higher than previous versions installed you can use the previous update-alternatives --config gcc command to check installed versions and use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove gcc
```

Or:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
```

NOTE: You could skip installing the PPA Repository and just use `/usr/bin/gcc-4.9-base` but I prefer using the fresh updated toolchains.

---

For GCC 5.X or 6, the packages (and correspondingly, the commands) are just called `gcc-5`, `gcc-6`, etc. This is due to the change in [GCC's version scheme](https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#num_scheme), where 5.1 is the first GCC 5 release, and [future 5.X releases are for bug fixes](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-announce/2015/msg00000.html).

Comment: Thanks for the edit @muru ...like I said below, I was up for about 3 days very tired and update-alternatives does requires sudo and I think I forgot the (--) before slave. :) So, Thank you.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: This works perfectly. Also, substitute `5` in for `4.9` to get GCC 5 working on Ubuntu. (My development team now runs both 4.9 and 5 alongside each other following your method.) Thank you, and +1!

Comment: I substituted `gcc-4.9` with `gcc-5` in the commands, but the eventual `gcc -v ` still shows the `4.x` version. Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: It works for gcc-5, but not for gcc-6. For gcc-6 it complains that it can't locate the package.

Comment: @hwat It should work for `gcc-6` now.

Comment: This has helped me several times, but I always forget - make sure to apply the same solution to other utilities in the GNU compiler collection you may use! GCOV for example will complain about a version mismatch if you do not, possibly producing incorrect data.

Comment: Needed this as help installing CLFS and using 16.10 as the host system.  6.2.0 in 16.10 is too new and causes build failures

Comment: saved the day  ...

Comment: Why Linux distributions are still supplied with GCC 4.9? Why aren't they going forward to GCC 7.x branch?

Comment: Full list of commands on https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91 is helpful:  includes configuring `update-alternatives`.

Comment: Confirmed working for gcc-10

Comment: May I suggest editing to explain the random `60` after the `/gcc.(version)` file? I found an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099787/865861). The `60` in my case didn't work because other versions were at `90`.

Comment: The 60 is the priority. The reason this didn't work for you is that you most likely had another version of gcc set as your alternative already with a higher priority. I don't believe that higher priority is the correct fix for everyone. I don't have time right this minute to do this but I can add an update-alternatives --remove-all for command for gcc.

Comment: I added a little information on checking and removing older versions of gcc for priority issues

Comment: If I run your "update-alternatives" command I get this error: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc` even though I've gcc-12 and gcc-11 installed.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct file location and name for gcc and g++. Use `which gcc` and `which g++` to find the locations
Ex:
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-12.2 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-12.2`

Answer (score 46):

**Ultimate mega master compatibility table**

OK let's do this:

```
                  GCC                clang
        +-------------------------+--------------------------------+
        | 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 | 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 |
+-------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 23.10 |  D  M M  M  M           |  D  M  M  M                    |
| 23.04 |  M  D  M  M M           |  M  D  M  M                    |
| 22.10 |     D  M  M M           |     D  M  M                    |
| 22.04 |     M  D  M M           |        D  M  M  M              |
| 21.10 |        D  M M M         |           D  M  M  M M         |
| 21.04 |        M  D M M M       |              D  M  M M         |
| 20.10 |           D M M M       |                 D  M M M M M   |
| 20.04 |           P D M M       |                    D M M M M   |
| 19.10 |             D M M       |                                |
| 19.04 |             M D M M     |                                |
| 18.10 |               D M M M   |                                |
| 18.04 |           P P M D M M   |                      M M M D M |
| 16.04 |             P P P P D M |                                |
+-------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

- **D**: Default GCC

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gcc g++
  gcc --version
  ```

  Whatever the `gcc` package aliases to: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc and also present in manifests: [How do I list the default installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48886/how-do-i-list-the-default-installed-packages)
- **M**: Present in Main repo

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gcc-X g++-X
  gcc-X --version
  ```

  All Ubuntu versions that have a hit for a given GCC version, e.g. for GCC 7: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-7 or clang 7 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang-7

  The minor versions of these packages can get updated from time to time, e.g. 8.3.0 to 8.4.0.
- **P**: `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`, which is owned by Ubuntu people and therefore can be trusted to not be a virus, although it is possibly unstable:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gcc-X g++-X
  gcc-X --version
  ```

  Full list: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test)

  The minor versions of these packages can get updated from time to time, e.g. 8.3.0 to 8.4.0.

Blank spaces on the table mean either "no package available" or "I didn't bother to check". Notably I've not been looking into PPA packages too thoroughly. Edits accepted.

All the questions:

- [install gcc-9 on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [How to install gcc-7 or clang 4.0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256/how-to-install-gcc-7-or-clang-4-0)
- [install gcc-9 on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [What are the GCC and clang versions available in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045066/what-are-the-gcc-and-clang-versions-available-in-ubuntu-18-04)

**How to set a non-default GCC as the default?**

E.g., you installed `/usr/bin/gcc-7` but you want to use that instead of `/usr/bin/gcc` when you run `gcc main.c`.

Use `sudo update-alternatives` as mentioned in other answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/581497/52975 It creates the required symlinks for you.

See also: [What exactly does `update-alternatives` do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do)

**How to build your own toolchain from source**

If even the PPA is not old/new enough for you, see this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/52454603#52454603
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305738/can-i-build-gcc-for-arm-with-an-x64-one/26306591#26306591

**Older GCC version questions**

- [Ubuntu 20.04 - gcc version lower than gcc-7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235819/ubuntu-20-04-gcc-version-lower-than-gcc-7)
- [How to use an older version of GCC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229774/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-gcc/1259320#1259320)

Comment: what if I want to have only one compiler version installed? how do I get rid of older one? and what does `update-alternatives` command, that other people suggest, do, that you do not have it in your answer?

Comment: and why is there a hole for Ubuntu 18.10 and GCC 9? It is not supported?

Comment: @NooneAtAll `update-alternatives` creates symlinks between `/usr/bin/gcc` and your GCC of choice. You should use it in conjunction with this answer if you want to make `gcc` be a non-default GCC: https://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do Empty case means not supported via the methods described above. Notably, the PPA appears to only support LTS releases of Ubuntu. I would not recommend using a non LTS version of Ubuntu except the latest release.

Comment: So, it is not possible to run the latest g++ (g++-11) on my very old PC with Lubuntu 16.04? There is not way at all?

Comment: @Chameleon either build from source or try to find another PPA

Comment: Any chance of updating for gcc-12?

Comment: @user7761803 it's not on the official Ubuntu PPA yet: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test so you have to either compile from source ( see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872229/how-to-edit-and-re-build-the-gcc-libstdc-c-standard-library-source/51946224#51946224 ) or find some other PPA.

Comment: Please update for gcc-13. I can see this package on the link from this answer (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test/+packages) but cannot install it on Ubuntu 22.04.
Update: seems I have to upgrade to 23.04 for this.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat yes. And also it seems GCC 13 is not released yet: https://www.phoronix.com/news/GCC-13-Ends-Stage-1-Development Let's wait a bit before adding it in the answer I think. If you need it, the best approach is to compile from source as per "How to build your own toolchain from source".

Answer (score 25):

Use the [Toolchain Test Builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
```

I don't think GCC 4.9 is fully available for Ubuntu 14.04 yet. The base package ([gcc-4.9-base](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gcc-4.9-base)) and the GCC Go 4.9 compiler ([gccgo-4.9](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gccgo-4.9)) are available, but the other frontends are not. I don't know why.

Comment: @SudoSURoot it may or may not be set as default, that's not my concern (there are other posts dealing with that). However, that GCC 4.9's C and C++ frontends can be installed on 14.04 purely from the official repositories is patently false, since the `gcc-4.9-base` package does not and will not contain a binary frontend.

Comment: You are correct about the base package. As you'll see in my answer, I used the PPA. I posted the comment first, then answered the question as stated, from question... Because simply adding the PPA and installing 4.9 does not enable it which is needed to "use gcc 4.9". I should have deleted the comment after I answered the question. I apologize. My answer is what should be focused on. I jumped to conclusions... and commented to fast. I am actually pretty new with using 14.04 since I got me dedicated server. I'm gong to make sure I didn't down vote and I'll fix it if I did.

Comment: @SudoSURoot alright. Even so, unless OP has a problem with calling `gcc-4.9` or `g++-4.9` instead of `gcc` or `g++`, I will stick to not updating the alternatives.

Comment: I totally understand. I build Android systems though, which uses a lot of $(which gcc) and $(which g++) etc... So I always have to have defaults set to the version I want to use. Some of my kernel code wouldn't compile with host gcc-4.8 so I had to update. I just repeated what worked for me. Thanks for reminding me though... Like I said in my edit, from last comment, I may have down voted, prematurely, if so I'll fix it. I had been up for 2 or 3 days working on my kernel source when I posted these. Everyone has their ways... I just found the more thorough my answer the less questions I g

Comment: The latest package is gcc-7 ATM

Answer (score 9):

### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

You can already install gcc 7.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 from the default repositories. To install gcc-7 in Ubuntu 17.10, 18.04 and 18.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7
```

To install gcc-8 in Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gcc-8
```

To install gcc-9 in Ubuntu 19.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gcc-9
```

You can install gcc-7 in Ubuntu 16.04 from ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install gcc-7
```

You can install gcc-8 in Ubuntu 16.04 from ppa:jonathonf/gcc-8.0.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-8.0  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install gcc-8
```

Multiple versions of gcc can be installed alongside each other. You can change the default gcc version by using the `update-alternatives` command to determine which actual file is referenced by a generic name, for example which actual file is referenced by `gcc`. For more information see the answers to this question: [How to change the default GCC compiler in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 4):

To call gcc 4.9 specifically, use `gcc-4.9` at the command prompt.

All the gcc versions you have installed can be called individually by adding a hyphen and the version number at the end of `gcc`.  In your case, `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-4.9` should be available. In a terminal, type `gcc-` (note the hyphen) and the push tab twice to see if there are any other versions installed.

Note that the default gcc is likely still 4.8.  (Use `gcc -v` to verify this.) Unfortunately changing the default is not trivial if you installed gcc-4.9 from the default repository as it did not add a update-alternatives entry. If you are interested in how to change the default, see answers to this [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version).

Comment: How do I make a project relying on makefile and possibly other build infrastructure build with `gcc-4.9` instead of `gcc`?

Comment: The best way to make sure gcc-4.9 is used across build systems is to change the default gcc. Follow the link I provided in my answer for how to do this. Alternatively you could create a symbolic link, though I recommend against this except as last resort since the package manager might complain when updating gcc. If you insist: `sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc; sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/gcc`. To revert to gcc-4.8 default, just replace gcc-4.9 with gcc-4.8. You may have to do this with g++ and other GNU compilers as well.

Comment: GCC 4.9 is not available in Ubuntu 14.04 (except for the [GCC Go compiler](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gcc-4.9)), so while this answer will probably work in Ubuntu 14.10, it doesn't help now. :-)

Comment: Actually it is available in Ubuntu 14.04, though it may have been a mistake: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gcc-4.9-base. I have been using it since April.