# Compiling C code for ARM processor on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, c++, c, arm, cross-compilation

I am compiling my simple "Hello world" C code using the following command:

1. `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4 test.cpp -o test`

   It generates an error:

   ```
   arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': 
   execvp: No such file or directory
   ```
2. My directory: `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.7` won't have any `cc1plus` file as the compiler is looking for `cc1plus` whereas my `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6` has the `cc1plus` file.

My `test.cpp` is a simple "hello-world" program, which I am going to target for ARM processor.

Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your file has `.cpp` extension, so `gcc` will try to compile with some settings for c++. `cc1plus` comes with g++ package, try installing it. I've faced a similar problem before.

1. Install ARM g++ cross compiller

   ```
   sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
   ```
2. Then use g++ instead gcc to get correct linking

   ```
   arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ test.cpp -o test
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` is a C compiler `g++` is a C++ compiler.

You're trying to compile a cpp file with the `gcc` compiler, try with the `g++` compiler instead.

Use the following command to install a g++

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Regards,
Rangineni Balu

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` is a C compiler and `g++` is a C++ compiler as mentioned in the answer from @rangineni balu.

But you can use `gcc` as well to compile a C++ program with `-libstdc++` as shown below:

`gcc -x c++ hello.cpp -lstdc++`

**Additional information:**

How to install [`gcc`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04)

To compile the C program:

`gcc hello.c -o hello`

To run it:

`./hello`