# What does priority mean in `update-alternatives`?

Tags: software-installation

What does priority mean in `update-alternatives`?

what does a smaller priority value mean？

How is priority related to and different from the default one "*"?

Thanks. For example:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.6                                1046      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java               1         manual mode
```

Answer (score 12):

From [`man update-alternatives`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html):

```
Each alternative has a priority associated with it.  When a link  group  is  in  automatic
mode,  the  alternatives  pointed  to by members of the group will be those which have the
highest priority.
```

It can be any integer, even negative (see example in manpage).

If the alternative is set manually, priority has no relation to the default.

Comment: So the highest the number the highest the priority ?

Comment: @thanos.a I believe yes, because this is way people set 10 for python3.7 priority.