# Install gcc 7.1 on Xubuntu 16.04 and make it default

Tags: xubuntu, gcc

I want to install the latest `gcc` package (7.1) on Xubuntu 16.04.4. I have successfully installed the package following the instructions given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371737/install-gcc-7-on-ubuntu) from GAD3R.

The problem is that when I run:

```
gcc --version
```

I get the following output:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

which means that my OS doesn't see the newly installed `gcc` as the default compiler. How can I achieve that?

Furthermore, I you have a more trusty source than the one presented in the link, please feel free to add it.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the toochain-r PPA that you used is the recommended source for alternate versions of GCC. To make it the default, you can either use the **update-alternatives** mechanism as explained in this previous Q&A

[How to use multiple instances of gcc?](https://askubuntu.com/a/313313/178692)

or by direct symlinking as described in

[Downloaded g++ 4.8 from the PPA but can't set it as default?](https://askubuntu.com/a/372268/178692)

---

Although in practice it's often not necessary, since most build systems allow you to specify a particular compiler, either using command-line arguments or environment variables e.g.

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-7 ./configure
```

or

```
make CC=/usr/bin/gcc-7
```

or

```
cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-7 ..
```

-- see for example [CMake Useful Variables](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables).

Comment: Great answer. Specifying the right gcc to cmake worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [update-alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) to make it default:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 60
```

For instance, this Dockerfile gives you Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 7:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y gcc-7 g++-7 && \
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 60 && \
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 60
CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. could you please also explain what that 60 is for at the end?

Comment: @Rika You need to specify a priority. In this example, using different values should not matter, so 60 is rather arbitrary. There is a related question about priorities: https://askubuntu.com/q/533391/117753

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it