# How to update from gcc 7.4.0 to 9 on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gcc

I installed gcc 9 using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-9.0
sudo apt-get install gcc-9
```

But running gcc -v (after restart) still gave the output of 7.4.0.
Additionally, I tried uninstalling gcc

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove gcc-7
```

and then installing gcc -9, but then running gcc -v says no file/directory found.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [Install gcc 7.1 on Xubuntu 16.04 and make it default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942784/install-gcc-7-1-on-xubuntu-16-04-and-make-it-default) - although you *can* make it default (either by manually symlinking, or by using `update-alternatives`) it's often simpler to just call `gcc-9` explicitly when you need it.

Comment: The ppa doesn't use a gcc dependency package so you'll not have a /usr/bin/gcc link to gcc-9.  `gcc-9 -v` would return info..

Comment: @Tistayu : The default system compiler gcc should not be removed. You can have as many gcc/g++ versions as you want, installed at the same time. .... `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` can select version.