# Use package without declaring its version

Tags: command-line, gcc, g++, update-alternatives

I have installed g++ from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain). When I want to compile a program, I have to use `g++-4.9 myle.cpp`.

How can I set it to use without declaring its version `g++ myle.cpp`?

Comment: make an alias of g++4.9 as g++

Comment: Use `update-alternatives`. See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/581497/158442

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose gcc and g++ version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version)