# How to install the latest g++(currently 5.1) in Ubuntu(currently 14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, g++

This question always bothers me! Last time for 4.9 I tried the commands mentioned in [this answer for g++4.9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04). The same trick doesn't work now:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-5.1 g++-5.1
```

results in...

```
E: Unable to locate package gcc-5.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-5.1'
E: Unable to locate package g++-5.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-5.1'
```

What is the correct command for directly installing the latest g++ in Ubuntu? Is there any *magic* command which works uniformly for all the updates of g++?

**Update**:

I found that the correct command to install it is:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-5
```

This works now! Though in the [GCC official page](https://gcc.gnu.org/), the version is 5.1.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

check the repo page https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test

It shows version 5 as latest version so you'll not find 5.1 and thus result this error

you should install using (it still version 5 in your given Repository)

```
sudo apt-get install g++-5
```

Else if this doesn't work you can download the source code and compile it

Comment: This is the correct answer.  However, I'd like to add that you may need to sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-5 to /usr/bin/g++ so you can call it directly with g++

Comment: By now 5.1 is in, too :)

Comment: g++-5 *is* g++-5.1. There was never a 5.0 release. I don't know why ubuntu stopped putting the minor version as part of the package name.

Comment: @TrevorHickey. this command "/usr/bin# ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/gcc-5’: File exists" not working...any idea how to do this linking operation?

Comment: @Ashu sudo rm -f /usr/bin/gcc since it's already there, and then run the ln command again.

Comment: The repo now mentions gcc-6, but I am unable to download that. Any idea why?

Answer (score 40):

Use the following command I found in [here](https://gist.github.com/beci/2a2091f282042ed20cda)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently the ubuntu repo skips the minor version naming. When I installed the gcc-5 and g++-5 packages, the version that gets installed on my computer is 5.2.1. Well I feel it is as latest as you can get without compiling by yourself. So do not worry about the 5 it is the latest version.