# How to install g++ 5.1 on Ubuntu desktop 15.04 64-bit?

Tags: apt, software-installation, gcc, c++

I'd like to experiment with the new GCC 5.1 C++ compiler on Ubuntu.

So, I downloaded and installed Linux Ubuntu desktop 15.04 64-bit in a virtual machine.

Then, in the terminal, I entered the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++5
```

Several packages where downloaded and installed; but when I enter:

```
g++ --version
```

I still get:

> ```
> g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2
> ```

I also tried (from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/618474/405901)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-5
```

But I still get 4.9.2 as output from `g++ --version`.

What should I do to try g++ 5.1, without building the whole thing from sources?
Is it possible to install pre-built binaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the latest g++(currently 5.1) in Ubuntu(currently 14.04)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618474/how-to-install-the-latest-gcurrently-5-1-in-ubuntucurrently-14-04)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GCC 5.x suite is not available in 15.04. You can get it by adding a PPA, such as https://launchpad.net/~nicola-onorata/+archive/ubuntu/toolchain

I am not sure if this will result in it being the default compiler though, so you may still need to call it as `g++-5`or similar, to use it. You may also have some serious issues with linking to certain C++ libraries that are included in Ubuntu 15.04, as it does have some incompatibility with 4.9, primarily where STL is concerned.

Comment: After it's installed, the system version of gcc should still show 4.* unless you change that. Typically, you just call gcc-5 when you want to use it by adding the flag CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5 to your commands.

Comment: That ppa doesn't exist anymore. Please remove this answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is EOL now too. The answer is not invalidated by the fact that it's old. The question is specifically about 15.04. At this point if you are on 15.04, you need to do everything on your own. It would be best to upgrade.

Answer (score 19):

I have not tested it on Ubuntu 15.04 but this is how I installed it on Ubuntu 14.04 from a PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
sudo update-alternatives 
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Alternatively you can download it and compile from source. I used to do that earlier, but it take a little bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a couple months old, if you did want g++ --version to output 5.1 follow these instructions: [How do I use the latest gcc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04) (hint: symlinks)

Answer (score 0):

15.04 is EOL now but when it was still in use, you could install `hardening-wrapper` which comes with `/usr/bin/gcc-5`.

The `gcc-5` package is now available on 15.10+.