# How can I update gcc 5.3 to 6.1?

Tags: software-installation, updates, gcc

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I found that `gcc 5.3` installed by default but I don't receive any updates to `gcc`. I opened up [GCC website](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/) and I found the new release 6.1. How do I update?

Output of `gcc --version`:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: See [How can I install and use gcc 6 on xenial?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/746369/how-can-i-install-and-use-gcc-6-on-xenial)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can install GCC 6 by adding the `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` PPA. To do so, run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-6
```

You can verify that `gcc-6` is installed by running `gcc-6 --version` and the output should say `gcc-6 (Ubuntu 6.1.1-2ubuntu12~16.04) 6.1.1 20160510`.

As suggested by Mohamed Slama, if you want to further change the default GCC and G++ to the latest versions, install g++-6 with

```
sudo apt install g++-6
```

and then run

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6
```

Comment: Are you using it? how stable is it?

Comment: @Videonauth I am not using it. I know from a colleague that GCC 6 introduced regressions that broke the compilation of a software that we use.

Comment: Ah o.k. well then i rather stay at 5.3.1 for now.

Comment: @Videonauth Yeah, there is no harm installing `gcc-6` though and trying to see if it works for you. Your gcc 5.3.1 is still around and `gcc` is still symlinked to `gcc-5` instead of `gcc-6`.

Comment: what does `60` do here?

Comment: its 2021 and These steps worked lika a charm for me.  I get gcc 6.5 version.  Latest yocto require  gcc > 6 so i think gcc-6 is stable now.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to build it from source (which I recommend as you can for example make a cross-compiler, etc.) download the source from a [mirror](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html).

Then extract it with:

```
tar -xvf gcc-6.1.0.tar.gz
```

After that change directory to there:

```
cd gcc-6.1.0
```

Then create `build` directory and `cd` to it:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

Then configure the makefile (`--disable-multilib` means to not build libraries for cross-compilation):

```
../configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
```

If you ran into errors due to missing required libraries or other prerequisites: (Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460654))

```
./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

And then build it:

```
make -j 8
```

This process may take some time and after done invoke this:

```
sudo make install
```

That's it!

Comment: While the `-j` flag speeds up the compilation quite a bit it is not advised to use it building tool-chain executables, and a `make check` should be run before installing.

Comment: Well that worked for me :) and I even built a cross compiler with it

Comment: I didn't say that it wont work, but `gcc` and `g++` are more than only compilers for C, C++.

Comment: But @Videonauth when I didn't use `-j` flag it took 3 hours to build it which was very frustrating :|

Comment: I know, and it takes even longer on older systems to make a full compile and check on my very old dual core laptop took 3 days all in all. You might want to have a look at [how a Linux is build from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/index.html) this might shed some light, they explain on those sites as well why compiling with flags is not the best idea if you plan to rely on it. Saying that i have successfully build a couple of personal used Linux systems myself meanwhile.

Comment: You should never do `sudo make install` on your distro without setting installation prefix first. Keeping up with different versions of self compiled and installed apps and being able to remove them afterwards will be really nasty after having few different versions compiled and installed to default prefix. Better to have separate directory for every version and to use stow (https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) or something similar to just handle symbolic links which will be installed under /usr/local

Comment: So now you have both version of gcc OR only latest one ?