# Install g++-9 for c++20

Tags: apt, upgrade, c++, g++

I would like to run the [full features](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/projects/cxx-status.html) of `c++20` on `g++`. However, I need to install `g++-9` for this purpose.

Following the installation [guides](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618474/how-to-install-the-latest-gcurrently-5-1-in-ubuntucurrently-14-04) for old versions of `g++` do not work for `g++-9`.

Any hint?

```
sudo apt install g++-9

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package g++-9
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-9'
```

.

```
sudo apt install g++9

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libconfig9' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libaac-tactics-ocaml-ibg92' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libounit-ocaml-dev-afg95:i386' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libjpeg9-dbg' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libjpeg9-dev' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libreins-ocaml-dev-rpyg9' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libaac-tactics-ocaml-dev-ibg92' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libjpeg9' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libflac-ocaml-77yg9:i386' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libflac-ocaml-dev-77yg9:i386' for regex 'g++9'
Note, selecting 'libaac-tactics-ocaml' instead of 'libaac-tactics-ocaml-ibg92'
Note, selecting 'libaac-tactics-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libaac-tactics-ocaml-dev-ibg92'
Note, selecting 'libreins-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libreins-ocaml-dev-rpyg9'
Note, selecting 'libflac-ocaml:i386' instead of 'libflac-ocaml-77yg9:i386'
Note, selecting 'libflac-ocaml-dev:i386' instead of 'libflac-ocaml-dev-77yg9:i386'
Note, selecting 'libounit-ocaml-dev:i386' instead of 'libounit-ocaml-dev-afg95:i386'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libaac-tactics-ocaml : Depends: libcoq-ocaml-d91z1
                        Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.02.3
                        Recommends: libaac-tactics-coq but it is not going to be installed
 libaac-tactics-ocaml-dev : Depends: camlp5-tli55
                            Depends: libcoq-ocaml-dev-d91z1
                            Depends: ocaml-nox-4.02.3
 libflac-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: libogg-ocaml-dev-465c2:i386
                          Depends: ocaml-nox-4.02.3:i386
                          Depends: libogg-ocaml-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libounit-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.02.3:i386
 libreins-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.02.3
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: GCC 9 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @muru the reference says `Range-based for statements with initializer  | P0614R1  | 9 `. Then how do they expect I test it?

Comment: Build [the current development sources of GCC from SVN](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/), presumably.

Answer (score 1):

Install g++ 8

```
sudo apt install g++-8
```

Run g++-8 with c++ 20 version.

```
g++-8 -std=c++2a text.c++ -o compiled
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this answers OP's question/issue?