# Trouble installing Clang and LLVM - no uint64_t definition

Tags: 14.04, make, clang

I ran `./configure`, but when I try to `make` `llvm`, I get the following error:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APFloat.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/static_analysis/llvm/include/llvm/Support/SwapByteOrder.h:19:0,
             from /opt/static_analysis/llvm/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:18,
             from /opt/static_analysis/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:20,
             from /opt/static_analysis/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h:14,
             from /opt/static_analysis/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/APInt.h:19,
             from /opt/static_analysis/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/APFloat.h:20,
             from /opt/static_analysis/llvm/lib/Support/APFloat.cpp:15:
/opt/static_analysis/build/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:77:3: error: #error "Don't have a definition for uint64_t on this platform"
# error "Don't have a definition for uint64_t on this platform"
^make[2]: \*** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APFloat.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: \*** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/all] Error 2
make: \*** [all] Error 2
```

P.S. I tried installing it by following these instructions - [Getting Started: Building and Running Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html)

Comment: What version are you trying to build? is there a particular reason you are trying to install from source rather than using the version provided in the package repository?

Comment: Honestly, I am new to Linux and the source way showed up when I googled how to install clang. May you tell me with a bit more details what the other way to do it would be? I just followed the tutorial, I may only assume it is the latest version.

Comment: Unless you *need* particular features that are not supported by the packaged version (which is clang-3.4 in 14.04), I'd recommend that you stick with that - at least for now. You should be able to install it just like any other package i.e. from Software Center or from a terminal using `sudo apt-get install clang`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was solved by installing a newer version of gcc, which is basically an answer in this thread: [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I guess a newer version of Ubuntu (15) automatically solves this problem because the default gcc there is 4.9 already.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by clearing the CMake cache. Just delete `CMakeCache.txt` and try running `make` again. `CMakeCache.txt` should be in the same directory you're trying to execute the CMake command in.

Comment: I edited the answer for clarity. I also had the `uint64_t not defined` error, I fixed it by clearing the CMake cache.