# How to use C++ 11 features in the latest version of g++

Tags: upgrade, c++, g++

Newbie here.
I just got an error running from the terminal a C++ program I wrote: `error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’`. They told me the compiler is too old.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

My g++ version is 4.8.4.

How do I upgrade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to upgrade. Specify the standards version to `g++`. For example, to compile [an example program from cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ --std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
$ ./test
std::stoi("45") is 45
std::stoi("3.14159") is 3
std::stoi("31337 with words") is 31337
```

Comment: so every time I use g++ I need to add `--std=c++11`? Can't I make C++11 the default standard?

Comment: @Pigna If you run `g++` that often, you should be [writing Makefiles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16886737/2072269).

Comment: @muru: If your machine pre-dates the standard then an update is required. Example: c++17/c++1z just released a few months ago, and my machine does not support the standard because its a few years old. Your answer is a solution to the OP's particular use case, not the posed question

Comment: @charlestoncrabb then you'd be looking for https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu. I don't really care about the posed question, because it's often the case that people think [they want X when they want to solve Y.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @muru What if you are compiling someone else's code and can't edit the MakeFiles.

Comment: That's why well-written Makefiles support `CC`, `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS` and the like.