# How to install gcc-7 or clang 4.0?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, gcc, c++, clang

I want to try C++17 features and I want to install standard compliant compiler (preferably GCC). I'm totally new to Linux and Ubuntu and I simply don't understand a lot.

I tried to follow https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test but with no luck. First I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

As I understood this command installs some keys. Next I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/gcc-7
```

That returned:

```
Error: 'ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/gcc-7' invalid
```

Next I tried to install clang development branch:

```
apt-get install clang-4.0 lldb-4.0
```

And it gives me

```
E: Unable to locate package clang-4.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'clang-4.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'clang-4.0'
E: Unable to locate package lldb-4.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lldb-4.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lldb-4.0'
```

What does all this means? What's wrong?

Comment: The `add-apt-repository` command you ran is not the same as the one given on the PPA's page, so it's no wonder it doesn't work. Try running the correct one.

Comment: I installed `test` package first. Updated the question.

Comment: `add-apt-repository` as its name implies adds a repository, it does not install a package. Now you can do `apt install gcc-7`.

Comment: The test PPA has a gcc-7 package in it. Have you not tried to install that?

Comment: I ran `sudo apt install gcc-7` command and got `Unable to locate package gcc-7`.

Comment: @nikitablack Looks like gcc 7 is not available for 16.04: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=xenial But you might have a better chance with clang, look at the base of this page: http://apt.llvm.org/

Comment: @andrew.46 Now I see that it's not available. Unfortunately I have the same problems with clang.

Comment: I'm using the LLVM source.list and it's the same error messages. Is it possible that `clang-4.0` removed from the souce lists, both on LLVM.org and Ubuntu repository? http://apt.llvm.org/

Comment: Hi! I'm a person from the future! The first two lines you tried seem to be sufficient on Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can already install gcc-7 and g++-7 from [this package](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
```

Comment: Yes, this works. As for today, this ppa also works `add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc-7`

Comment: clang-4.0.0 gets installed but clang -v shows 3.8.0 .

Comment: Both are installed 4.0.0 and 3.8.0 but by default system reads 3.8 . Which messes up while using Emscripten which reads this but requires 4.0.0.

Comment: is this repo running from a residential connection or something?

Answer (score 33):

Super mega GCC table for all Ubuntu versions: [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu/1163021#1163021)

**Ubuntu 16.04 and below**

There is an official Ubuntu GCC test PPA which should be preferred:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
gcc-7 --version
```

GCC 7 was release in [May 2017](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html), so too late for 17.04 main release.

The PPA does not currently have GCC for newer releases e.g. 16.10, only LTS 12.04, 14.04 and 16.04, as can be seen at: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test | [snapshot](http://archive.is/DTFgf). I think it had 17.04 previously but it was removed?  See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371737/install-gcc-7-on-ubuntu

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, October 2018.

**Ubuntu 17.10 and above**

Has GCC 7.2 and clang 4 by default! https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/gcc | https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/clang

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0
$ clang --version  
clang version 4.0.1-6 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
```

**GCC 8 on 16.04**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-8 g++-8
gcc-8 --version
```

gives 8.1.0 as of 2018-11.

Default in Ubuntu 18.04:

- [Install gcc-8 only on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028601/install-gcc-8-only-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc-8

**Crosstool-NG**

If you are really serious about this, compile and use your own GCC with Crosstool-NG as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/52454603#52454603

This will allow you to use a wide variety of GCC versions on a wide variety of Ubuntu versions without downloading blobs from PPAs you don't necessarily trust.

Comment: upvoted! i am grateful for this help. after these steps I also needed to run `update-alternatives` as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/980495/231504

Answer (score 2):

OP asks for "how to install...". Alternatively, how to compile Clang 4.0.

You may compile from the source code using the script from Microsoft [ChakraCore's GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/master/tools/compile_clang.sh).

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/master/tools/compile_clang.sh
```

Update `LLVM_VERSION="3.9.1"` at line 7 to `LLVM_VERSION="4.0.0"`

```
sudo ./compile_clang.sh
```

It will download and compile Clang 4.0 (and whole compiler toolchain) with LLVM Gold support.

Comment: What's "LLVM gold"?

Comment: @einpoklum I suppose it's the [LLVM gold plugin](https://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html) for the Gold Linker from Binutils. It's used for link-time optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Here my step to install gcc-7/g++-7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS **AND** make it the default.

First to install gcc-7/g++-7 using the official ppa.

```sh
sudo apt update -qq
sudo apt install -yq software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update -qq
sudo apt install -yq g++-7
```

with:

- `-y`: auto confirm
- `-q`: quiet mode (several increase the quiet level)

Then make it the default alternative

```sh
sudo update-alternatives \
 --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 60 \
 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 \
 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-7 \
 --slave /usr/bin/gcov-tool gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov-tool-7 \
 --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-7 \
 --slave /usr/bin/gcc-nm gcc-nm /usr/bin/gcc-nm-7 \
 --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-7
```

now running `gcc --version` should return gcc 7.4.0 IIRC