# How to upgrade gcc-5 to gcc-7 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, gcc

This is a follow up question to [How to install gcc-7 or clang 4.0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256).

Following the answers therein, I was able to install gcc-7.2 by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y gcc-7
```

However, after the install, the `gcc`/`g++` command still defaults to `5.4.0`

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Is it possible/safe to have `gcc-7` as the default and remove the old gcc-5.x files entirely?

---

Note that, different from the said duplicate, I'm looking to *remove/replace* gcc-5.x instead of setting a symlink.

Comment: You cannot remove `gcc` because it depends on `gcc-5`, and packages may break if they depend on gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question after much trial and error, it seems *not* safe to remove/replace the older gcc (gcc-5), because it will break a lot of dependencies to the extent of wiping out the entire tool chain.

For example, when trying to remove/replace gcc-5 as said in the comments with

> Run update-alternatives to set gcc-7 as the default gcc version and
>   the type sudo dpkg -r gcc-5

This generates an error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of gcc-5:
 g++-5 depends on gcc-5 (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04).
 g++ depends on gcc-5 (>= 5.3.1-3~).
 gcc depends on gcc-5 (>= 5.3.1-3~).
 gfortran-5 depends on gcc-5 (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04).
```

When adding these dependencies to the list of `sudo dpkg -r` items, an increasing number of packages need to be removed. e.g.

```
 ...
 r-base-dev depends on g++.
 build-essential depends on g++ (>= 4:5.2).
```

I haven't tried to find the largest set of packages that will be removed as described in [How to uninstall a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/) . But it's pretty clear that most of the useful packages in the Ubuntu will be gone by then.