# Install gcc-8 only on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gcc, 18.04

I just installed Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. There are two options for installing gcc: `gcc-7` and `gcc-8`. Both are available from `apt-get install` out of the box.

Even after I installed `gcc-8`, the system is still going to install `gcc-7` when I install other packages such as `build-essential`.

Since `gcc-8` is newer, is there a way to make it install `gcc-8` and `gcc-8` only?

Comment: Just don't install `build-essential` but the other packages it depend on directly? `dpkg-dev g++-8 gcc-8 libc6-dev libc-dev make`

Comment: gcc-7 is required by gcc-8. **Note :** You can have as many gcc/g++ versions as you want, installed at the same time. Bionic extras  : `g++-4.8 g++-5 g++-6 g++-8` ... ... g++-7/gcc-7 is the system compiler. The older versions are required for building some older applications.

Comment: @KnudLarsen "gcc-7 is required by gcc-8" what?

Answer (score 96):

`gcc-7` and `gcc-8` will happily co-live together.

I would suggest to let `gcc-7` be installed, for satisfying `build-essential` and perhaps other dependent packages, and configure `gcc-8` to be your default gcc installation.

Use [`update-alternatives`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) for having `gcc` redirected automatically to `gcc-8`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 700 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 800 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8
```

This will give you the convenience of gcc being at the latest version, and still you will be able to invoke `gcc-7` or `gcc-8` directly.

If you'll wish to change the default gcc version later on, run `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`. It will bring a prompt similar to this, which lets you pick the version to be used:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gcc-8   800       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gcc-7   700       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gcc-8   800       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

The higher priority is the one that is picked automatically by `update-alternatives`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 24):

**Master table of all GCC versions for each Ubuntu**

At: [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu/1163021#1163021)

**GCC 8 on Ubuntu 16.04**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-8 g++-8
gcc-8 --version
```

gives 8.1.0 as of 2018-11. See also:

**GCC 9 on Ubuntu 19.04**

```
sudo apt install gcc-9
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-9

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This information could be relevant for a completely separate question, but that one already does have the answer: https://askubuntu.com/q/466651/113421.

Comment: @Ruslan thanks for feedback. Helping 100x Googlers is more important than helping 1 OP ;-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli冠状病毒审查六四事件法轮功 Thank you! Saved my day... and Nice Profile picture btw :P

Comment: @user1241241 thanks! I'm glad you like my discreet profile.

Comment: Got gcc-9, but not gcc-8. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go download **unversioned** gcc packages (`cpp`/`gcc`/`g++`/`g++multilib`/etc.) with package version 8, and install them using `dpkg -i *.deb`. Make sure you have the corresponding packages with `-8` suffix installed first.

http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/

Reason:

build-essential and a lot of other packages depend on **unversioned** packages (no version number in package name) such as `gcc`, `g++`, etc., and those **unversioned** packages depend on **versioned** packages (whose package name contains a version as suffix) such as `gcc-X`, `g++-X`, respectively.

A **unversioned** package `gcc` with package version `8.~` depends on `gcc-8`, whereas the `gcc` package in offcial Ubuntu 18.04 repository comes with package version `7.~`, which in turn depends on `gcc-7`.

Those **unversioned** gcc packages install nothing, just act as dependency declaration to the **versioned** gcc packages.
The **unversioned** packages from Debian 10 (codename buster) are versioned with `8.~`. You can safely manually install them and the dependent **versioned** packages are still from your official ubuntu repository, so it's totally safe to do so.