# Error while compiling bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: wireless, kernel, broadcom, gcc

Recently, the WiFi on option on my Ubuntu 16.04 disappeared. I figured that `bcmwl-kernel-source` needed to be updated so what I basically did was:

> sudo apt-get upgrade

When the upgrade reached `bcmwl-kernel-source`, I ended up with the following error:

> Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-131-generic (x86_64)
>
> Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
>   modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-131-generic
>   update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

So I checked the log file and here is what it showed:

[Log file of compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5pzq.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Here is some information regarding the WiFi card:

> Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
>       DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
>       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build error suggests you are using gcc <= 4.8:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option `-fstack-protector-strong`
```

The `-fstack-protector-strong` option was only introduced with gcc version 4.9.

By installing a more recent gcc version, and configuring it as your default gcc (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028601/install-gcc-8-only-on-ubuntu-18-04/1028656#1028656) for example), you should be able to build successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much. Switching to gcc 5.4 and purging bcmwl-kernel-source before reinstalling it worked :)

Comment: @Einsiedler glad to have helped :-)