# Upgrade gcc (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2) to gcc-8 (8.2.0) in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 18.04, gcc

Has recently upgraded my ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04.1 LTS. When trying to run vmware I am getting this message: **gcc version 8.2.0 not found**
so I checked gcc v. and I found: `(Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)`.
I tried to install gcc-8 following these steps:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && sudo apt update &&
 sudo apt install -y gcc-8`

But I got this: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: gcc-8: depends:
cpp-8, gcc-8-base and libgcc-8-dev`
So I downloaded gcc-8 from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc-8
 , But I don't know how to install it and if this is the right way?!
Any suggestions or help is very appreciated - I don't know how to do it.

`Build-essential: newest v.: 12.4ubuntu1
 Kernel: 4.17.12-041712-generic`

Comment: The second link you provided tells you the package is available in the 'universe' repository for bionic (18.04), so can be installed with `sudo apt install gcc-8` (assuming you have 'universe' repository enabled; the dependencies are also found in universe)  ie. `apt` will do the download for you & then install.  Do you have 'universe' enabled?  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for help with repositories ; at the first picture you need to have the second box (universe) ticked.

Comment: yes..I have `universe` enabled. I tried installing gcc-8 using aptitude and it seems installed(/usr/bin/gcc-8), but when I check the v. i still getting 7.3 so I tried to update the alternatives: `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` , but i don't found the choice of gcc-8 (just gcc-5, 6, or 7)!!! any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to add this:  I tried now `sudo apt install gcc-8` and i am getting:  `gcc-8 is already the newest version (8.1.0-1ubuntu1)`!!!

Comment: I only use the default `gcc`, so this is from looking only. A `dpkg-query -S gcc-8` shows the file "/usr/bin/gcc-8" is installed (*& as you stated*); so I'd guess `gcc-8` would run it.  Is that what you tried?   Otherwise this was found online - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028601/install-gcc-8-only-on-ubuntu-18-04  (see answer)

Comment: I tried your suggestion: `dpkg-query -S gcc-8 ` and it's correct, i get `gcc-8: /usr/bin/gcc-8` and some "/usr/share/../". the problem now i cannot find g++-8 (i have g++-5, g++-6 and g++-7) to update the alternatives of gcc as your link describe it!!! do you have g++-8?! - and thanks for helping me

Comment: AFAIK additional versions of gcc will **not** overwrite the default `/usr/bin/gcc` symlink - if you gcc-8 to be the default, you will need to symlink it yourself (or place gcc under the control of update-alternatives). Otherwise, just use `gcc-8` as the program name when you want to run it

Comment: Thanks for both of you. Now my gcc -v is `gcc version 8.1.0 (Ubuntu 8.1.0-1ubuntu1) `...finally!