# Ubuntu 14.04 with 384.47 NVidia driver - blank screen

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, nvidia-geforce

I got a new PC with AMD Ryzen 1700X and Geforce GT Nvidia 1030

Old PC had AMD A10 with built-in video something, and Kubuntu 14.04.05 on kernel 4.12

Moved old SSD into the new one and got a black screen after GRUB.

Logged into terminal in safe mode, downloaded latest driver 384.47 from NVidia, but it won't DKMS with kernel 4.12 ("this kernel version is not supported").

Earlier kernels don't seem to support Ryzen

Earlier drivers don't seem to support NVidia 1030

Latest driver don't seem to compile with the latest kernel.

How do I get the system up and running?

Answer (score 0):

The **solution** was found in log files - this driver requires one of the newer command line parameters of gcc and 14.04 ships with gcc 4.8 so it won't compile.

**You will need gcc 4.9+**. Default will not change is you just install gcc-4.9, so either you need to remove 4.8 or set symlinks in /usr/bin/gcc to the newer one.

Please refer to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu) how to install gcc 4.9

Comment: Please learn how to install drivers directly from the official repositories or the semi-official PPA, if needed, instead. That is the preferred method.

Comment: That would have worked if they included this dependency on gcc 4.9

Comment: Perhaps they weren't expecting people to run brand new hardware in 3 years old releases... Maybe it works just fine in 16.04 LTS or the current 17.04. Either way it's a problem you brought in yourself, mostly.

Comment: 14 is the current lts release (see list of releases) supported until year 19. Some people prefer to stay with stable and fast KDE 4 rather than 5+

Comment: ... and don't reinstall for years. This 1030 graphic card is the cheapest new card they had in the shop, so many will buy it for office desktops. These assumptions made me come here and spend my time asking and answering my own question here. Hope this will save their time if they have issues.