# What are the GCC and clang versions available in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gcc, versions, compiler

In the new Ubuntu 18.04:

- What's the default GCC version (with which the binaries were built)?
- What GCC versions are available as separate packages (and what minor version is installed if I install GCC 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8 respectively)?
- What Clang versions are available as separate packages (and what minor version is installed if I install clang 4 or 5?)

I can't find this in any release notes (and I don't want to have to install just to check.)

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=gcc

Comment: and https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=clang

Comment: I'm maintaining a list of all GCC versions for all Ubuntus ever at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu/1163021#1163021

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters, I checked Ubuntu's [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=gcc) [server](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=clang):

- Default compiler: GCC 7.4.0
- Can install: GCC 4.8.5, GCC 5.5.0
- Can install from the "universe" repositories: GCC 6.4.0, GCC 8 (version string 20180414, not quite sure what that means)
- Can install: clang 6.0 (default version), clang 3.9.1, clang 4.0.1, clang 5.0.1

If you add the [toolchain-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic), you can also install GCC 8.1.0.

Comment: The `gcc-8` package (and plenty of related packages) are in the _universe_ repository, but in 18.04 it is I think a pre-release version.

Comment: Also, `gcc-6` is installable as well, as version 6.4.0.

Comment: »version string 20180414« means : Year 2018 Month 04 Day 14. ... **Note**: You can have as many compiler versions as you want, installed at the same time.

Comment: @KnudLarsen: Of course that's a date, but what does that date mean? Is it related to a release? To a certain branch? Surely it's not the GCC trunk...

Comment: `gcc-8 (8-20180414-1ubuntu2)` is a git / svn version dated eighteen days before the official release https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/ ... Debian added 133 patches http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/gcc-8_8-20180414-1ubuntu2.diff.gz

Comment: @KnudLarsen: Before which official release? The 8.0 release? 8.1 release? Because the file you linked to says GCC 7.