# install gcc-9 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, ppa, repository, gcc

gcc-9 is just [released](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/).

I was wondering if there is a repository that allows me to install gcc 9 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic)?

There seems to be repositories supporting disco:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gcc-9-base

But I liked to have it on the current LTS for a while.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It is now available in [ubuntu-toolchain-r](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) too:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-9
```

If the `add-apt-repository` command cannot be found, run this:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Above commands install just c compiler, if you need c++ compiler (g++) too

```
sudo apt install g++-9
```

Comment: just as a reminder to people reading this `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9`

Comment: To make @JHBonarius 's useful comment complete, you need to install g++ along with gcc, i.e. `sudo apt install  gcc-9  g++-9`

Comment: @JHBonarius: What does your command do?

Comment: @TorKlingberg, `apt install gcc-9 g++-9` installs binaries with names `gcc-9` and `g++-9` in Ubuntu 18.04, if you want to use `gcc` & `g++` then `update-alternatives` provides convenient way to do it. And if you have multiple different versions of gcc (and not just gcc) you can create alternatives for all of them and then easily switch between them.

Comment: Not working on Bionic : ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-9-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libc6-dev-x32 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32gcc-9-dev : Depends: lib32gcc-s1 (>= 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
(...)
 libx32gcc-9-dev : Depends: lib32gcc-s1 (>= 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
(...)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa, I've just tested it in docker, still installing fine. Either you have something else conflicting installed or something wrong with your packages db.

Comment: Yep, I add to use `aptitude` to force the installation, then it worked. `apt` alone would not install it.

Comment: I upgraded my kernel to `5.3.0-050300-generic` and VM multiplayer required this version of  `gcc`,  it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

I used a search for **PPA**s, using [search on launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) and found JonathonF's [GCC 9.0 **PPA**](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc?field.series_filter=bionic). You can install this package by:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-9
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I changed PPA to "repository" accordingly.

Comment: Edited my answer and removed info about PPAs and repositories (to be more neutral).

Comment: Note: you need to `sudo apt-get update` before the install.

Comment: @EntangledLoops Why? AFAIK, there is an automatic update after calling `add-apt-repository`.

Comment: @ZhengQu Yes, it appears that's another thing that changed in 18.04. I was running 16.04 at the time.

Comment: This command gives me `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~jonathonf/ubuntu/gcc-9.0'.
ERROR: '~jonathonf' user or team does not exist.` 
Is this answer is out of date now?

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` before `add-apt-repository ...` fixed this.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happened in the  past week, but deploying again, and `gcc-9` seems to have gone missing (`g++-9` still installs)

Comment: edit: I NEEDED to run `sudo apt-get update` after `add-apt-repository` on ubuntu 18.04.4 (Jetson nano)

Comment: This is no longer working, is there another source repository for this ? The user named '~jonathonf' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/gcc-9.0'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:

Comment: Thanks, @LennyD . Answer updated.

Comment: This now gives me `E: Unable to locate package gcc-9` on `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`

Comment: This is no longer working. Same output as @SoylentGraham.

Comment: Debian is off-topic here. Just tested on supported Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, all commands work normally; *`gcc version 9.2.1 20191109 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-19ubuntu1~18.04.york0)`*. You should ask support for Debian on different site.