# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found even though libstdc++.so.6 recent enough

Tags: shared-library, glibc

I realize there are many questions like this, but the difference from the others is that my libstdc++.so.6 actually does appear to be up to date enough (see below for the strings it exports). This is an error that comes up when trying to load a dynamic library that i just compiled myself. `apt-get upgrade`  and the like tell me libstdc++.so.6 already is up to date (on version `libstdc++6 is already the newest version (9.1.0-2ubuntu2~18.04)`).

Full error i get when loading this library (in MATLAB R2019a):

```
'/home/dee/git_repos/Titta/TobiiMex/TobiiMex_matlab/64/TobiiMex_matlab.mexa64':
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by
/home/dee/git_repos/Titta/TobiiMex/TobiiMex_matlab/64/TobiiMex_matlab.mexa64)
```

output of `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC`:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

What can i try to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Installing `libstdc++6` and `gcc-9` helped me. Hope it will help you too.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-9
sudo apt install libstdc++6
```

Comment: Unable to locate package gcc-9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Then you have to check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

may `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` help?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with libstdc++.so.6 which was working in R on command line but not from the rstudio IDE.
Instead of having the latest version of it in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (rstudio default) it was in a conda environment (/home/user/myproject/envs/default/lib).
For me it was the answer of Brent81 that solved it.
I used
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/myproject/envs/default/lib`
and it worked.

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng`
solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Search for other versions of `libstdc++.so.6` in your system. You are probably picking up an older version of the dynamic lib.

Comment: Why voting this down? In FreeBSD `libstdc++.so.6` is within gcc packages which could coexist. So the lib could coexist, which will raise such problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. Previously I installed Insomnia using **snap**

And just *uninstalling* and *reinstalling* using **snap** didn't change anything.

But installing it using `apt-get` [solve for me](https://docs.insomnia.rest/insomnia/install)

---

Just be aware that your personal data will not be automatically imported by the new installation

In fact, I'm not sure what happens to the user data after uninstalling the snap version of the software. Case you figure it out, please let me know

Comment: Exactly my problem and the solution worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Installing matlab-support package in ubuntu 18.04 solved the problem for me

```
sudo apt install matlab-support
```

It mention something about renaming libraries, that can be of help:

```
Tried renaming /opt/MATLAB/R2021b/sys/os/glnx86/libgcc_s.so.1
Tried renaming /opt/MATLAB/R2021b/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6
Renaming /opt/MATLAB/R2021b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgcc_s.so.1 to /opt/MATLAB/R2021b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgcc_s.so.1.bak.
Renaming /opt/MATLAB/R2021b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6 to /opt/MATLAB/R2021b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.bak.
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem

Make sure the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`doesn't point to undesire location

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: This needs some explanation what is an undesire location?