# Virtualbox6.1 Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel5.4.10

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I recently had virtualbox6.1 working on this system, I updated the kernel from 4.15 to 5.10 and I'm getting this message when I try to open a VM

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.

Alright fair enough, I run the command as requested:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.
There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

And the messages have this mess of text to say:

```
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/5.4.10-050410-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j8 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 single-build= need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvGip.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvGip"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvSem.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvSem"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvTracer.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvTracer"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPLibAll.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPLibAll"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPLibAll.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/.alloc-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"alloc_r0drv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/.initterm-r0drv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"initterm_r0drv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.c
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
./arch/x86/include/asm/page_64.h: In function ‘clear_page’:
././include/linux/compiler_types.h:210:24: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘__inline’
 #define asm_inline asm __inline
                        ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:256:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘asm_inline’
  asm_inline volatile (ALTERNATIVE_2("call %P[old]", "call %P[new1]", feature1,\
  ^~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/page_64.h:49:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘alternative_call_2’
  alternative_call_2(clear_page_orig,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/barrier.h:5:0,
                 from ./include/linux/compiler.h:256,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/include/iprt/types.h:150,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/include/iprt/initterm.h:33,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:128:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
  "# ALT: oldinstr2
"         \
  ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:168:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘OLDINSTR_2’
  OLDINSTR_2(oldinstr, 1, 2)     \
  ^~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:256:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ALTERNATIVE_2’
  asm_inline volatile (ALTERNATIVE_2("call %P[old]", "call %P[new1]", feature1,\
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/page_64.h:49:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘alternative_call_2’
  alternative_call_2(clear_page_orig,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
./arch/x86/include/asm/page_64.h: In function ‘clear_page’:
././include/linux/compiler_types.h:210:24: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘__inline’
 #define asm_inline asm __inline
                        ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:256:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘asm_inline’
  asm_inline volatile (ALTERNATIVE_2("call %P[old]", "call %P[new1]", feature1,\
  ^~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/page_64.h:49:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘alternative_call_2’
  alternative_call_2(clear_page_orig,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/barrier.h:5:0,
                 from ./include/linux/compiler.h:256,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/include/iprt/types.h:150,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/include/iprt/mem.h:34,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h:128:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
  "# ALT: oldinstr2
"         \

****omitted similar looking nonsense****

./arch/x86/include/asm/bug.h:79:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘_BUG_FLAGS’
  _BUG_FLAGS(ASM_UD2, BUGFLAG_WARNING|(flags));  \
  ^~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/bug.h:98:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__WARN_FLAGS’
   __WARN_FLAGS(BUGFLAG_ONCE |   \
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/kobject.h:134:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘WARN_ON_ONCE’
  WARN_ON_ONCE(kref_read(&kobj->kref) == 0);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:265: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o] Error 1
Makefile:1652: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0' failed
make[1]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:114: recipe for target 'vboxdrv' failed
make: *** [vboxdrv] Error 2
```

Tips from other questions suggested installing virtualbox-dkms to fix this, installing it removes virtualbox6.1 but I tried anyway but the kernel drivers still failed to install.

I've tried installing linux-headers-5.4.10-050410-generic but they're already installed so no benefits from that.

I'm not sure where to look for a solution, apparenly this is supposed to 'just work:' [VirtualBox 6.1 Released with Kernel 5.4 Officially by Oracle Team](https://www.tecrobust.com/virtualbox-6-1-released-with-kernel-5-4-officially-by-oracle-team/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar.
In my case the kernel headers where installed but corrupted.
I re-installed them by:
sudo apt --reinstall install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

After that /sbin/vboxconfig worked fine.

Although in your case I suspect that the Kernel version is not compatible.

Comment: I tried the command you suggested, apt reports there's no download candidate so it failed. In light of your idea i followed the directions at https://www.askmetutorials.com/2019/11/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-54-on.html to install the 5.4.0 kernel and headers which installed correctly but vbox still failed to install the kernel drivers on 5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Ubuntu 18 ships with gcc 7, and a newer version is needed in order to compile with kernel 5.x

I installed gcc 9 as explained in [install gcc-9 on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install gcc-9
```

Then, I set the new version as default (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu)

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 50
```

Reinstall kernel headers, just in case

```
 sudo apt --reinstall install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

After this steps, `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` runs without problems.