# man shows old version of g++ despite installing newer version

Tags: gcc, manpage

I've installed gcc-9 and g++-9 as written in this answer
[answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1149383/941978)
 and updated the alternatives as shown in the comment, still when I type `man g++` it shows the man page of the previous version.
The output of `gcc -v` and `g++ -v` is 9.2.1

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 is the version

Comment: I  have ubuntu 16.04 and give me some time I will test it in 18.04 in a docker container

Comment: What was the old version?

Comment: Checking for version : `$ gcc --version`... or `$ gcc -v`. ... About man pages ( $ man gcc ) : The link made with "update-alternatives" is for /usr/bin/ only, not ///man/

Comment: @bhordupur, the old version was gcc-7

Comment: so what do I do to show the latest manpage, should I create a symlink ?

Comment: If you want the man page to reflect the selected binary alternative, you should probably add it as a *slave* when you install the link group

Comment: is gcc-9 default one?Have you verified that? I could not reproduce it. I guess you better update your questions with more info.

Comment: @steeldriver I would be grateful if you tell how I could do that