# How to update GCC to 11.2

Tags: 20.04, gcc, g++

Today I installed *Ubuntu 20.04* (first time using Linux) and I'm having trouble with updating **GCC** to **11.2** (latest stable version). I checked another question and tried it but after updating it, it's still showing this:

```bsh
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

Also, I want to uninstall all the older versions and only keep **11.2**. Is this possible? Or even recommended?

Comment: Please link the other question and also the command you used to obtain the gcc version you have listed. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163021/167115)

Comment: @mchid Yes, thanks. I did it. Now it's on **11.1.0**. Do you know a way I can update to 11.2? Cause that was the one I was using on Windows prior to deleting it and migrating to Linux.